# Internal Server Error occurs with ajax POST method in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**View CODE:**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".price").click(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function () {
       if ($(this).val()) {
          $("#priceSave").show();
       }
       else {
          $("#priceSave").hide();
       }
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">
<!--<form name="priceform" method="post" action="addPriceDetails/{{$dataId}}">-->
 <div class="modal fade" id="price">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Selling Information</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-content">
     
       <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <b>Listing Information</b>
          <h6>Seller SKU ID  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Unique identifier for the listings">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
        <input type="text" name="skuid" id="skuvalue" class="pricevalue" />
          </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <b>Status Details</b>
          <h6>Listing Status  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Inactive listings are not available for buyers on Flipkart">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <select id="dropDownId" name="listingStatus">
          <option selected disabled>--Choose here--</option>
          <option value="Active">Active</option>
          <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
          </select>
          </div>
          </div>
           <br/>
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Price Details</b>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h6>MRP  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Maximum retail price of the product">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="mrp" id="mrpvalue" class="check-fill"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h6>Your Selling Price   <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Price at which you want to sell this listing">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="selprice" id="selpricevalue" class="check-fill"/>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
           <br/>
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Inventory Details</b>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h6>Fulfilment By  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Fullfilment of FA listings will be managed by Flipkart ">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <select id="5" name="fulfillment">
          <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
          <option value="Seller">Seller</option>
          </select>
          <br/>
          <h6>Procurement SLA  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Time required to keep the product ready for dispatch">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="sla" class="check-fill"/>Days
          <br/>
  <h6>Stock available for Buyers  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of items available for cutomer to buy after detecting pending orders" >
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="available" readonly/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h6>Procurement Type  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Information on how the inventory is procured by the seller to fulfill an order">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <select name="procurementType">
          <option selected disabled>--Choose here--</option>
          <option value="instock">instock</option>
          </select>
          <br/>
          <h6>Stock  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of items you have in stock">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="stock" />
          <br/>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
           <br/>
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Delivery charge to customer</b>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h6>Local Delivery Charge  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Delivery charge you want charge a buyer in the same city for listings which are not Flipkart Assured">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="local" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h6>Zonal Delivery Charge  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Delivery charge you want charge a buyer in the same zone for listings which are not Flipkart Assured">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="zonal" />
          </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h6>National Delivery Charge  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Delivery charge you want charge a buyer outside your zone for listings which are not Flipkart Assured">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="national" />
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
           <br/>
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Packaging Details</b>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
          <h6>Package Weight  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Weight of the final package in kgs">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="weight" />Kgs
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <h6>Package Length  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Length of the final package in cms">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="length" />cms
          </div>
           <div class="col-sm-3">
          <h6>Package Breadth  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Breadth of the final package in cms">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="breadth" />cms
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <h6>Package Height  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Height of the final package in cms">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="height" />cms
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
           <br/>
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <b>Tax Details</b>
          <h6>HSN  <a href="#" class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="code of your product for determining applicable tax rates">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:
#337AB7"></span>
        </a></h6>
          <input type="text" name="hsn" />
          <a href="#">Find relevant HSN codes</a>
          </div>
          </div>
           <br/>
          <br/>
         <input type="submit" id="priceSave" class="save" value="Save" style="border-radius: 8px; padding: 5px 15px; display:none;">
      <!-- </form>-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!--<button type="submit" id="priceSave" class="save" style="border-radius: 8px; padding: 5px 15px; display:none;">Save</button>-->
      </div>
    
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
</div>
```

This is my laravel view code. Here when I click on the input fields it shows up the "SAVE" button. When I click on the save button, I am trying to redirect to the controller using ajax(code mentioned below).

SCRIPT CODE:

```
 <script src = 
 "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajaxSetup({
   headers:{
 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
 }
 });
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#priceSave").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
         url: '{{url("addPriceDetails")}}',
                type: "post",
                success:function(data) {
                  alert(data);
              } 
 });
  });
 });
</script>
```

This is the script code,I have tried for redirect using ajax with the help of post method.

ROUTE CODE:

```
Route::post('addPriceDetails','priceDetails@addPriceDetails1');
```

Controller:

```
 public function addPriceDetails1()
 {
   echo("1234");
 }
```

My controller code.ON redirection it shows Internal server error on browser console page.

Comment: You're attaching a new `keyup` event handler on every each click of `.price`

Comment: Is that the one affects my question

Comment: Is there anyone??